# how to avoid uploading base image on dockerhub?

Tags: docker

I have built one image whose base is tensorflow/tensorflow image
when i try to push my image to dockerhub, it is showing that it requires more than 1.5GB to upload

```
563696d99850: Layer already exists  
143e5fff24a3: Layer already exists  
0c1be9bb1e3d: Pushing [====>                                              ]  5.963MB/65.23MB  
b7a1811f2ea8: Pushing [==========================================>        ]  8.522MB/10.13MB  
f871135480f9: Layer already exists  
0ffcfa94cbd7: Pushing [===>                                               ]  6.658MB/83.39MB  
d988b477570e: Layer already exists  
3ac411c5111b: Layer already exists  
fb527dc12c46: Pushed  
cb90a867c0cd: Pushed  
5a670d7dd0c6: Pushed  
6c92ecfa77e9: Pushing [>                                                  ]  **4.286MB/1.757GB**
5b96a3898347: Pushed  
019cc58032ea: Pushing [=====>                                             ]  1.273MB/10.98MB  
0f02bf561d26: Waiting  
63d29dc0e589: Waiting  
28ba7458d04b: Waiting  
838a37a24627: Waiting  
a6ebef4a95c3: Waiting  
b7f7d2967507: Waiting
```

is there any way to avoid this?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install opencv-python-headless

COPY model.py .
COPY model_08015_07680.h5 .
COPY images /usr/src/app/images
COPY labels.txt .
COPY test_run.py .



CMD ["python","./test_run.py"]
```

i have pulled the image tensorflow/tensorflow

Comment: Could you add your Dockerfile to the question?

Comment: added the docker file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can avoid the whole uploading thing with **automated builds**.

Docker Hub can automatically build images from source code in an external code repository service (GitHub and Bitbucket only) and automatically push the built image to your account.

I won't go into details here as Docker docs already have a dedicated page with detailed information on [automated builds](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/).